# require sub modules in express app

Tags: node.js, express

Why doesn't the following work ?

```
  app.js
  reports/
  ├── index.js
  └── batch.js
```

in `app.js` :

```
app.use('/reports', require('./reports')
```

in `index.js` :

```
var express = require('express');
var batch = require('./batch');
var app = express.createServer();
...
app.use('/batch', batch);
module.exports = app;
```

in `batch.js` :

```
var express = require('express');
module.exports = function() {
  var app = express.createServer();
  console.log('I am here');
  app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    console.log('I am there');
  });
  return app;
};
```

calling `GET /reports/batch` prints `I am here` but doesn't print `I am there`

Can anyone pinpoint me to the problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I have forgotten javascript a little.

I was doing

```
app.use('/batch', batch);
```

`batch` is equal to

```
function() {
  var app = express.createServer();
  console.log('I am here');
  app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    console.log('I am there');
  });
  return app;
};
```

Instead I should have done

```
app.use('/batch', batch());
```

Which equals to what `express.createServer()` returns which is what `app.use` expects to get

Comment: Are you using Express 2.x? `express.createServer()` is deprecated in Express 3.

Comment: @robertklep Yeah, unfortunately hadn't had the change to update yet. A lot of breaking changes...

Answer (score 2):

try this:

in app.js :

```
var express = require('express'),
    http = require('http'),
    path = require('path');

var app = express.createServer();

require('./reports')(app);
```

in reports/index.js :

```
module.exports = function(app){
    var batch = require('./batch')(app);

    app.use('/batch', batch);
}
```

in batch.js :

```
module.exports = function(app) {
  console.log('I am here');
  app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    console.log('I am there');
  });
};
```

Note that you may need to modify the app.get routing as needed.  but basically the idea here is instead of calling createServer all the time just keep passing it down the chain from one module to the next.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I actually prefer the modularity of creating express app each time. As you can see on [this video](http://vimeo.com/56166857) by Express creator, it's a common pattern. i'm doing something wrong in `index.js` file, just can't figure out where exactly I mess things up

Comment: I don't think it would make a difference but have you tried:
`module.exports = function(){ var express = require('express'); ... app.use('/batch', batch); }`

Comment: @Michael there's "modularity" and there's "code reuse". The number of cut-and-paste actions in that video is mindboggling...

Comment: For simple apps sure, creating an express apps each time is fine, but in more complex apps that rely on different things being done at different stages, and in some cases changes to the app being passed down with least amount of code changes, I still think my method is a better route to take.  I do love how there are so many different ways to cut the pie when it comes to node though :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my app.js. It passes db and app to the feature.js. Basically they share the same app variable.

in app.js

```
    var express = require('express'),
    http = require('http'),
    path = require('path'), 
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://abc:123@xxxx.mongohq.com:90000/app123423523');
    var app = express(); 
    //here you set app properties
    require('./routes/feature').with(app, db);
```

in feature.js

```
    module.exports.with = function(app, db) {
                   //do work
    }
```